# Replacing NULL values with one string from provided list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, null

I am trying to replace NULL values in table by using SELECT with one (randomized?) string from the set that I provide to the compiler.

Example:

```
|id | date |
+---+------+    
| 1 | 2017 |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |
```

I want the `NULL` values to be '2015', '2012', etc, taken randomly from the set I specify.

Unfortunately `COALESCE` returns only first not null value rather than one from the specified. Is there some function that works like:

```
IF column_value = 'NULL (or something)' THEN RAND(string1, string2, string3, string4).
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like

```
SELECT Id,
       ISNULL(Date, (SELECT TOP 1 *
                     FROM   (VALUES(2015),
                                   (2012)) R(Ryear)
                     ORDER  BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(DATALENGTH(Id))))
FROM   YourTable
```

The reference to `Id` in the `ORDER BY` is just to make it correlated so that SQL Server is less likely to spool the result and replay it for multiple rows.
Select a column that is unique for this.

BTW: There is a `CHOOSE` function that looks tempting but when this gets expanded out to `CASE` the random number function gets copied out too and so this is not suitable for the task.

**Don't use this**

```
SELECT Id,
       CHOOSE(1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) % 2),2015,2012)
FROM   YourTable
```

**Because it is evaluated as**

```
CASE
  WHEN (1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) % 2)) = 1
    THEN 2015
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN (1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) % 2)) = 2
        THEN 2012
      ELSE NULL
    END
END
```

(And `CASE ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) % 2) WHEN 0 THEN 2012 WHEN 1 THEN 2015 END` would have the same problem)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is indeed covering my concern.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `NEWID()` in combination with BINARY_CHECKSUM()

```
declare @t table(id int,dates varchar(20))
insert into @t VALUES (1,'2017'),(2,NULL),(3,NULL)

declare @parameter table(para varchar(20))
insert into @parameter VALUES ('2015'),('2012')

    SELECT Id,
       ISNULL(Dates, (SELECT TOP 1 *
                     FROM   @parameter 
                     ORDER  BY  (ABS(CAST(
(BINARY_CHECKSUM
(id, NEWID())) as int))
% 100)))
FROM   @t
```

**Great Martin Smith**, I learn new thing now that I will share.

When I use table variable example then Inside (Select top 1 *..) fire for each row ,hence it work fine.It row get diff value

```
SELECT Id,
       ISNULL(Dates, (SELECT TOP 1 *
                     FROM   @parameter 
                     ORDER  BY  NEWID()))
FROM   @t
```

but in same query if I use `temp table or permanent table` then it fire only once so each null rows get same value

```
SELECT Id,
       ISNULL(Dates, (SELECT TOP 1 *
                     FROM   @parameter 
                     ORDER  BY  NEWID()))
FROM   #t
```

So one can deduce one difference between table variable and temp table/permanent.

Therefore one should be beware when using table variable with even 10 rows and more and that too using sub-query like above

Comment: Notice any pattern in these results? http://rextester.com/CJVT91769

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith,check my edited.My answer should not be downvoted as it is like "Test case" for others.